# Is it possible to document API keys in Springfox?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

I am trying to generate an OpenAPI (Swagger) document from Java code by using Springfox and Swagger Core annotations.

Is there any way to document an API key using annotations?

In https://editor.swagger.io, I can write it like this:

```
api_key:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "api_key"
    in: "header"
```

which would produce the following in Swagger UI:

[image: Secured operation indicated in Swagger UI]

Are there any Java annotations that would produce the same result?

Comment: What version of Swagger Core do you use - 2.x (latest) or 1.5?

Comment: @Helen I am using 2.x(2.9.2)

Comment: So you use Springfox? Or JAX-RS + Swagger Core?

Comment: I am using Springfox